# Caliburn.Micro: Pass the parent DataContext property to the viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm using Caliburn.micro in my WPF project. Model has two classes:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
public class Answer 
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

The viewmodel has a collection of Questions and a method for displaying the text of the question (for example):

```
public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Question>();
public void Show(object obj)
{
    if (obj is Question question)
        MessageBox.Show(question.Text);
}
```

In view, a ListView is bound to this collection:

```
<ListView Name="Questions" ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Text}" />
                <ListView Name="Answers" ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}" Grid.Row="1">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Button cm:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=Questions}" cm:Message.Attach="Show($dataContext)" />
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Text}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The difficulty is that when I click on a button in the list of answers, I need to pass not the DataContext of the current answer, but the DataContext of the question in which this answer is located, to the Show($dataContext) method. How can I do that?
`<Button cm:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=Questions}" cm:Message.Attach="Show($dataContext)" />`
I want to pass the parent object Question. I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to bind to the parent `ListView` using a `RelativeSource`:

```
cm:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
```

Comment: This leads to the same result. The Show() method is passed the Answer on which the click event occurred. I need something like: `cm:Message.Attach="Show($parent.DataContext)"`